# The upload now button doesn't display properly on manual mode

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

See the following link for reference: http://www.mcaprint.com/support/fileUpload.aspx

How can we fix this? I even tried copying exactly what was on the demo page and I got exactly the same result.

Answer (score 0):

You simply haven't included the proper CSS on your page.  Based on the class names, it looks like you are depending on Bootstrap's styles, but haven't included Bootstrap's CSS file on your page.

Comment: Thanks, that fixed it. While you're here, please update the following: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21261295/setting-up-an-upload-server